# I got an error in my magento test automation framework

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento

I try to run the magento test automation framework with net beans, I got this error

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(SymfonyComponents/YAML/sfYaml.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Programs\mtaf\framework\Mage\Selenium\Helper\File.php on line 29
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'SymfonyComponents/YAML/sfYaml.php' (include_path='C:\Programs\mtaf\framework;C:\Programs\mtaf\testsuite;.;C:\Programs\PHP\pear') in C:\Programs\mtaf\framework\Mage\Selenium\Helper\File.php on line 29
```

But all the pear components and unit components are installed successfully.

The below commands are used to install the pear and php unit.

```
C:\Programs\PHP>pear upgrade
C:\Programs\PHP>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
C:\Programs\PHP>pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
C:\Programs\PHP>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
C:\Programs\PHP>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
C:\Programs\PHP>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
C:\Programs\PHP>pear install phpunit/DbUnit
C:\Programs\PHP>pear install symfony/YAML
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tryed Unit tests on Magento but I would follow their instructions from github's magento taf repository.
You forgot an instruction `> pear install pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.2`
For more instructions on installing Test Automation Framework take a look [here](https://github.com/magento/taf/blob/master/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf)

I believe that your instruction `pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml` will install latest version of Yaml for symfony 2 (Magento uses symfony-project.com -> symfony 1)